# "TypeError: Cannot join tz-naive with tz-aware DatetimeIndex" using yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, yfinance

I am still new to coding and I have a problem with my code. I try several things but I don't understand why I still got all these error messages when I run my code. If someone could help me since I am on it for a long time now, it will be very nice.
You will find below my code and the error messages. Thank you.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download('AAPL',
 start='2000-01-01',
 end='2010-12-31',
 progress=False)
df = df.loc[:, ['Adj Close']]
df.rename(columns={'Adj Close':'adj_close'}, inplace=True)

df['simple_rtn'] = df.adj_close.pct_change()
df['log_rtn'] = np.log(df.adj_close/df.adj_close.shift(1))

QUANDL_KEY = 'LGgsMWx1VdrEv7r2R3Ve'
quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = QUANDL_KEY


df_all_dates = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(start='1999-12-31',
 end='2010-12-31'))
df = df_all_dates.join(df[['adj_close']], how='left') \
.fillna(method='ffill') \
.asfreq('M')


df_cpi = quandl.get(dataset='RATEINF/CPI_USA',
 start_date='1999-12-01',
 end_date='2010-12-31')
df_cpi.rename(columns={'Value':'cpi'}, inplace=True)

df_merged = df.join(df_cpi, how='left')

df_merged['simple_rtn'] = df_merged.adj_close.pct_change()
df_merged['inflation_rate'] = df_merged.cpi.pct_change()


df_merged['real_rtn'] = (df_merged.simple_rtn + 1) /(df_merged.inflation_rate + 1) - 1
```

And the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\.............., line 68, in <module>
    df = df_all_dates.join(df[['adj_close']], how='left') \
  File "C:\Users\.............., line 9969, in join
    return self._join_compat(
  File "C:\Users\.............., line 10008, in _join_compat
    return merge(
  File "C:\Users\.............., line 125, in merge
    return op.get_result(copy=copy)
  File "C:\Users\.............., line 776, in get_result
    join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
  File "C:\Users\.............., line 1015, in _get_join_info
    join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = left_ax.join(
  File "C:\Users\.............., line 317, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\.............., line 230, in join
    join_index, lidx, ridx = meth(self, other, how=how, level=level, sort=sort)
  File "C:\Users\..............
    raise TypeError("Cannot join tz-naive with tz-aware DatetimeIndex")
TypeError: Cannot join tz-naive with tz-aware DatetimeIndex

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: A traceback is the thing that shows you where the error happened, it's not a kind of error. The specific kind of error is TypeError; in this case, it's one caused by mixing timezone-aware with timezone-unaware timestamps. I've edited the question title to that effect.

Comment: ...as such, the solution would be fairly simple -- either convert your timestamps to all be timezone-aware, or such that _none of them_ are timezone-aware.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for your answer and your precision. I have tried to convert my timestamps such that none of them will be timezone-aware but it didn't work. Do you have any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: I don't generally do much with pandas, numpy or yfinance, so no, I'm not the best person to answer this question -- that's why I just edited it so folks who _do_ know those libraries would be able to better recognize the problem and, hopefully, add an answer.

Comment: Okay no prob. Appreciate it! Thank you